# How to align my current working components with Allure Framework?

Tags: allure

I'm beginner here, working on automating my functional test using Selenium, Visual Studio C#, and Team Foundation Server for my project. Currently, my test reporting are generated into a huge chunk of html files. It is hard for me to compiling and visualizing all the test results in charts.

Thus, i would like to ask for some ideas or guidance regarding how to align my current work with Allure framework?

Thanks. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: What are you talking about? Allure does all visualization for you! What is actually hard for you?